# REST API Azure Event Hub ExpiredToken

Tags: java, api, rest, azure, azure-eventhub

I'm testing the API using the Rest tool Chrome client to validate that the POST request I make is right in order to use it in a Java application. My request is in the following format:

```
POST /androidhub/publishers/android/messages?timeout=60&api-version=2014-01 
HTTP/1.1 HOST: androidhub-124.servicebus.windows.net 
authorization: SharedAccessSignature sr=androidhub-124.servicebus.windows.net&sig=mykeySAS=&se=146480684&skn=RootManageSharedAccessKey 
content-type: application/json, application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8 
content-length: 45  { "DeviceId":"dev-01", "Temperature":"37.0" }
```

But I have the following error.

```
<Error>
<Code>401</Code>
<Detail>ExpiredToken: . TrackingId:2f6d284e-d7d2-4c9c-81a5-79c542ce8eee_G7, SystemTracker:androidhub-124.servicebus.windows.net:androidhub/publishers/android/messages, Timestamp:5/25/2016 7:13:33 PM</Detail>
</Error>
```

The key was regenerated before I used it. How I can I not get that error or make the request without putting the time of expiration of the key?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my experience, if the `se` value `146480684` was correctly post here, I think the issue was caused by the `expiry` time as the `se` key which is measured in seconds between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.

So the `expiry` time as the value of the `se` key should be got using Java code below.

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
int expiry = (int)(now/1000) + 3600;
```

As reference, you can refer to the offical document for C#, please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt652140.aspx.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, use your code to generate a valid time and use it in the post method I get the following error:

401: 40103: Invalid authorization token signature

Similar to 403 Forbidden, but Specifically for use When authentication is possible but has failed or not yet Been provided. The response must include a WWW-Authenticate header field container containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource. See Basic access authentication and digest access authentication

You do not know that is?

Comment: @DiieGooRAlt i am facing the same issue. Did you find any solution

Answer (score 0):

Along with setting the correct `se` value, you will also have to ensure that the `sig` is a cryptographically signed (Using HMAC 256) base64 string consisting of both the namespace (in your case `androidhub-124`) and the `se`, using the SAS key for signing.

Example code to generate the `sig` in java is provided by Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/generate-sas-token):

```
private static String GetSASToken(String resourceUri, String keyName, String key)
{
    long epoch = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000L;
    int week = 60*60*24*7;
    String expiry = Long.toString(epoch + week);

    String sasToken = null;
    try {
        String stringToSign = URLEncoder.encode(resourceUri, "UTF-8") + "\n" + expiry;
        String signature = getHMAC256(key, stringToSign);
        sasToken = "SharedAccessSignature sr=" + URLEncoder.encode(resourceUri, "UTF-8") +"&sig=" +
                URLEncoder.encode(signature, "UTF-8") + "&se=" + expiry + "&skn=" + keyName;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return sasToken;
}


public static String getHMAC256(String key, String input) {
    Mac sha256_HMAC = null;
    String hash = null;
    try {
        sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
        sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);
        Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();

        hash = new String(encoder.encode(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(input.getBytes("UTF-8"))));

    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return hash;
}
```